# How can i test something like if it's the format of car plate?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, test

I need to test if an input it has the fromat of a car plate (0000-XYZ) and from the japanese ZIP wich the format is 000-0000

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  This looks like a pretty simple Regular Expression.  What have you tried? How did it not work as intended or expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `0` in your examples means "any single digit" and that `XYZ` is "any string of three upper-case letters".  The code below further assumes a POSIX locale.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for string do
        case $string in
                ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z])
                        printf '"%s" looks like a number plate\n' "$string"
                        ;;
                ([0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
                        printf '"%s" looks like a Zip-code\n' "$string"
                        ;;
                (*)
                        printf 'Cannot determine what "%s" is\n' "$string"
        esac
done
```

This uses globbing patterns to match each of the given strings and determine what the type of it is, or whether its type can't be determined.  The strings are given on the command line of the script.

Testing:

```
$ ./script 1234-ABC 234-2345 AAA-BB
"1234-ABC" looks like a number plate
"234-2345" looks like a Zip-code
Cannot determine what "AAA-BB" is
```

Using regular expressions in `bash` instead:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for string do
        if [[ $string =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[A-Z]{3}$ ]]; then
                printf '"%s" looks like a number plate\n' "$string"
        elif [[ $string =~ ^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$ ]]; then
                printf '"%s" looks like a Zip-code\n' "$string"
        else
                printf 'Cannot determine what "%s" is\n' "$string"
        fi
done
```

(Identical output as above given the same command line arguments.)

Answer (score 0):

I have made a script. I hope I understood you properly

```
#! /bin/bash

for plate do
[[ $plate =~ ^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$ ]] && echo "$plate : Japanese Plate" && continue
[[ $plate =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[A-Z]{3}$ ]] && echo "$plate : Normal Plate" && continue
echo "$plate : INVALID INPUT" 
done
```

Very easy and reproducible.

I would like to state I am TERRIBLE at coding, bash is no exception. Took this as a challenge to try and improve my skills a bit.

FEW TERMINAL OUTPUTS:

```
INPUT:    bash testfindnew.sh 000-1234 0000-XYZ 000-00000 0000-XYZZ
OUTPUT:   000-1234 : Japanese Plate
          0000-XYZ : Normal Plate
          000-00000 : INVALID INPUT
          0000-XYZZ : INVALID INPUT
```

Comment: Takes the least file size. Can take multiple arguments now. Very easy to see how it works.

Answer (score -3):

You may use regex in bash script. for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

car_plate="0000-0000"
if [[ $car_plate =~ ^[0-9-]+$ ]]; then
    echo "standard"
elif [[ $car_plate =~ ^[0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]; then
    echo "japanese"
fi
```

Comment: Those patterns do not enforce the template to match ("three digits, hyphen, four digits" or "four digits, hyphen, three letters"), it just tests that it has some unknown number of valid characters.